# Remove indent after optimization problem using optidef

Tags: indentation, optidef

Can any help me remove the indentation of the text after defining an optimization equation using the `optidef` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}

\begin{document}

The optimization problem is defined as
\begin{argmini!}
    % Optimization variable
    {R,L_{\beta},\beta}
    % Objective function
    {\frac{\left\lVert Z_{\text{FRAC}}(R,L_{\beta},\beta,\omega) - Z_{\text{FEA}}(\omega)\right\rVert^{2}}{\left\lVert Z_{\text{FRAC}}(R,L_{\beta},\beta,\omega) + Z_{\text{FEA}}(\omega)\right\rVert^{2}} \label{eq:objectiveFunction}}
    % Optimization problem label
    {\label{eq:optimizationProblem}}
    % Optimization results
    {}
    % Constraints
    \addConstraint{R}{> 0, \quad R &&\in \mathbb{R}}
    \addConstraint{L_{\beta}}{> 0, \quad L_{\beta} &&\in \mathbb{R}}
    \addConstraint{0 \leq \beta}{\leq 1, \quad \beta &&\in \mathbb{R} \label{eq:betaConstraint}}
\end{argmini!}
where $Z_{\text{FRAC}}(R,L_{\beta},\beta,\omega)$ is the impedance calculated from the fractional model  and $Z_{\text{FEA}}(\omega)$ is the impedance determined by FEA.

\end{document}
```

[image: exampleOutput]

Comment: Did you try adding `\noindent`?

Comment: @Bernard it does not help.

Comment: looks like a bug in the package. It's probably best to contact the package authors and ask them to take a look.

Comment: @thymaro I've now opened an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/jeslago/optidef/issues/29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in the latest version of [optidef on GitHub](https://github.com/jeslago/optidef). Just download `optidef.sty` and add it to your working directory.